# How operation in ng-repeat limitTo syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-limitto

I am new to use AngularJS 1.4.x .

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

ng-repeat='item in items | **limitTo:10:{head.value}* 10'**

i hope can use operatione in limitTo syntax ,how to let it work fine ???

This is my hope [image]

```
<div ng-repeat='head in heads' class='row'>
    <div class='colhead'></div>
    <div ng-repeat='item in items |limitTo:10:{head.value}* 10' class='colNumber'>
        <div ng-if='items.indexOf(item) == 0' id='ck-button'>
            <label>
                <input id={{item.value}} type='checkbox' value={{item.value}} ng-model='item.select' ng-click='toggleAll(item)'> <span> {{item.value}} </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div ng-if='items.indexOf(item) !=0' id='ck-button'>
            <label>
                <input id={{item.value}} type='checkbox' value={{item.value}} ng-model='item.select' ng-click='toggle(item.value, selected)'> <span> {{item.value}} </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/F3A1Ht?p=info

Comment: I have no idea of what you're trying to do. The second argument of limitTo is supposed to be an index in the array. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @duke see my updated answer..that would provide you the answer,,exactly what you wanted here

Comment: That's great ~~~~~~~
Thank you a lot~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `begin` of your limitTo using `head.value*10` value without `{}` curly braces.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items |limitTo:10:head.value*10' class='colNumber'>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kh7lMCrBGJF9H324MaYW?p=preview)

Comment: @Duke look at updated code..which provides you the solution what you want..?